# Lists in Python targeting specific characters

Tags: python

I'm currently learning about lists in Python and I have a specific case that I don't really understand.

```
L=['hello','pie']
L[0][1]
'e'
```

Why does L[0][1] output as 'e'? I understand that L[0] = 'hello'. So I don't really understand how L[0][1] = 'e'.

Answer (score 4):

Because you can also index **strings** in Python.

```
In [1]: L = ['hello', 'pie']

In [2]: L[0]
Out[2]: 'hello'

In [3]: 'hello'[1]
Out[3]: 'e'

In [4]: L[0][1]
Out[4]: 'e'
```

Answer (score 4):

A string in python is treated as a sequence of characters for purposes of indexing. Thus the string `'hello'` can be indexed as if it was the list `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`. As the index `[1]` refers to the second item in a sequence, you'll get the second letter of the string, `'e'`.